# Magento - Loop through all products in category, change value and save

Tags: php, magento, loops, collections, foreach

I need to loop through all the products in a particular category, change a custom attribute and then save each product.

Currently i have:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_POST['id']);
$all_products = $_category->getProductCollection();

foreach ($all_products as $product) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());  
    $product->setCustomAttribute(xxxx);
    $product->save();
}
```

Is this best practice and can it be improved for performance? The collections average around 15-20 products in each and i am getting a very slow loadtime or even the script timing out.

I've used `set_time_limit(0);` to try and force it through but i imagine i can improve my code to stop me having to do this? Eventually the collections may have over 100-200 products each so need to find a good performance now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a massive update of the same attribute and for the same value, consider trying `updateAttributes`:

```
// Iterate over the foreach and get all the product ids into an array
// $attr = array("attribute_code" => "attribute_value");
Mage::getSingleton("catalog/product_action")->updateAttributes($productIds, $attr, $storeId);
```

It should be much quicker.